# How to let users control ANY and ALL for ExpressionEngine categories using dynamic parameters?

Tags: expressionengine

My site has many entries, each having several categories assigned to them. Using Dynamic Parameters, I'd like to allow users to filter the entries to show only those belonging to certain categories, perhaps by selecting checkboxes. That part I know how to do.

The categories parameter in the Channel Entries tag lets you indicate that you want to show entries with ANY of the selected categories (category="2|45|4|9") or ALL the selected categories (category="3&7&8").

Is there any way to let users make the selection of ANY or ALL when they interact with the Dynamic Parameters form? So effectively, they could say either "Show me entries belonging to ANY of the categories I've selected" or "Show me entries belonging to ALL of the categories I've selected"?

Comment: Hi Mike.  There's much more EE activity over the dedicated site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. Thanks!